# Long lists of pass-by-ref parameters versus wrapper types

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference

I need to get three objects out of a function, my instinct is to create a new type to return the three refs. Or if the refs were the same type I could use an array. However pass-by-ref is easier:

```
        private void Mutate_AddNode_GetGenes(ref NeuronGene newNeuronGene, ref ConnectionGene newConnectionGene1, ref ConnectionGene newConnectionGene2)
        {

        }
```

There's obviously nothing wrong with this but I hesitate to use this approach, mostly I think for reasons of aesthetics and psycholgical bias. Are there actually any good reasons to use one of these approaches over the others? Perhaps a performance issue with creating extra wrapper objects or pushing parameters onto the stack. Note that in my particular case this is CPU intensive code. CPU cycles matter.

Is there a more elegant C#2 of C#3 approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For almost all computing problems, you will not notice the CPU difference.  Since your sample code has the word "Gene" in it, you may actually fall into the rare category of code that would notice.

Creating and destroying objects just to wrap other objects would cost a bit of performance (they need to be created and garbage collected after all).

Aesthetically I would not create an object just to group unrelated objects, but if they logically belong together it is perfectly fine to define a containing object.

Comment: PS - Managing data on the stack is VERY efficient compared to managing data in the heap.

Comment: @Eric, why won't you put that comment in your answer?

Comment: Because it was faster to add a comment after the fact?  Is there a reason I'm not aware of to edit the answer rather than post a comment?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worrying about the performance of a wrapping type (which is a lot cleaner, IMHO), you should use a struct. Current 32-bits implementations of .NET (and the upcomming 64-bits 4.0) support inlining / optimizing away of structs in many cases, so you'd probably see no performance difference whatsoever between a struct and `ref` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Worrying about the relative execution speed of those two options is probably a premature optimization. Focus on getting the algorithm correct first, and having clean, maintainable code. When that's done, you can run a profiler on it and optimize the 20% of the code that takes 80% of the CPU time. Even if this method ends up being in that 20%, the difference between the two calling styles is probably to small to register.

So, performance issues aside, I'd probably use a container class. Since this method takes only those three parameters, and (presumably) modifies each one, it sounds like it would make sense to have it as a method of the container class, with three member variables instead of ref parameters.